# Text to Binary JS

Tags: javascript, binary

I'm working on a piece of code to turn text to binary. First, I turn the text to decimal, then the decimal to binary. The problem I'm getting, is in the 'decimalToBinary' function, it is telling me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined", could someone explain what's wrong?

```
function start() {
    var text = readLine("Input the string you would like to encode: ");
    var binary = textToBinary(text);
    println(binary);
}

function textToBinary(text) {
    var toASCII = [];
    var toBINARY = [];
    text.toUpperCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var ASCII_CODE = text.charCodeAt(i);
        toASCII.push(ASCII_CODE);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < toASCII.length; i++) {
        var arrnum = toASCII[i]
        var final = decimalToBinary(arrnum);
        toBINARY.push(final);
    }
    return toBINARY;
}

function decimalToBinary(decimalValue) {
    var binaryBase = 2;
    var numBitsDesired = 8;
    var binaryValue = decimalValue.toString(binaryBase);
    while (binaryValue.length < numBitsDesired) {
        binaryValue = "0" + binaryValue;
    }
    return binaryValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've some typos in your code:

```
function textToBinary(text){
    var toASCII = [];
    var toBINARY = [];
    text.toUpperCase();
    for(var i = 0 ; i < text.length ; i++){
        var ASCII_CODE = text.charCodeAt(i);
        toASCII.push(ASCII_CODE);
    }
    for(var j = 0 ; j < toASCII.length ; i++){ // <- This should be j++ instead of i++
        var arrnum = toASCII[i] // <- Same here; j instead of i (i is off limits).
        var final = decimalToBinary(arrnum);
        toBINARY.push(final);
    }
    return toBINARY;
}
```

By accessing an array with an invalid index (out of bounds), you're getting an `undefined` value.

Comment: Thanks! That always seems to be my problem when I use two for loops in the same function!